# Fire input event from Angular 5 test

Tags: angular, jestjs, dom-events

I've been trying things and looking at the Angular docs for an hour plus, and still can't get this test to pass. I'm using Jest (which is very similar to Jasmine). The thing is, it's working in the app when I `ng serve`, I just can't write a passing test for it!

**HTML template**

```
 id="typeahead-plan"
   placeholder="search"
   type="text" class="form-control br--top"
   [(ngModel)]="selections.clientId"
   [ngbTypeahead]="searchClients"
   (input)="resetFileId()"
   (blur)="filterFileIds()"
   (keyup.enter)="filterFileIds()"
   (selectItem)="selectClientPlan($event.target.value)" />
```

**Spec**

```
test('Submit button is disabled when changing plan', () => {
  component.resetFileId = jest.fn();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const submitEl = fixture.debugElement.query(
    By.css('button[data-test=submit]')
  );
  const planInputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#typeahead-plan'));
  expect(submitEl.nativeElement.attributes['disabled']).not.toBeDefined();

  planInputEl.nativeElement.value = 'd';
  planInputEl.triggerEventHandler('input', null);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(component.resetFileId).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(submitEl.nativeElement.attributes['disabled']).toBeTruthy();
});
```

The test says that the spy was expected to have been called, but it never was, so that leads me to think I'm not triggering the input event correctly. If I comment out the `toHaveBeenCalled` assertion, then the next one fails, as the submit button doesn't have a `disabled` attribute. Again, it's all working fine clicking through the UI manually, just not in the tests. This kind of thing keeps rearing its head as I try to learn how to write tests, and it's really frustrating and slowing down my development.

Comment: Where have you created your spy?

Comment: @AmitChigadani First line of the test: `component.resetFileId = jest.fn();` The expectation passes if I explicitly call `component.resetFileId()` but it should be getting called as the `(input)` event calls it.

Comment: Can you try `planInputEl.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))` instead of `planInputEl.triggerEventHandler('input', null);` ?

Comment: I had tried that, it didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like I have to include an object with a target when raising the event. The [Angular docs](https://v5.angular.io/guide/testing#triggereventhandler) state:

> The test assumes (correctly in this case) that the runtime event handler—the component's click() method—doesn't care about the event object.
>
> Other handlers are less forgiving. For example, the RouterLink directive expects an object with a button property that identifies which mouse button (if any) was pressed during the click. The RouterLink directive throws an error if the event object is missing.

However, they don't say what the "other handlers" are, or what they need, which seems to be a glaring omission.

So, if I do: `inputEl.triggerEventHandler('input', { target: inputEl.nativeElement });` then the event fires and it detects that the function was called.